# Does using named arguments cost performance in kotlin?

Tags: performance, kotlin

I like using the named arguments feature of kotlin for methods with multiple parameters of the same type. However, I wondered if there is a performance penalty for that. For example, in python, named arguments are realised with a hashmap, while positional arguments are realised with an array which is usually cheaper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short Answer

No, there is no performance penalty for using named arguments per say.
The compiler converts the use of named arguments to normal method call with positional arguments.

#### Long Answer

Using named arguments produces the same bytecode as using positional arguments.
However, changing the order of the arguments leads to the creation of temporary variables. This is because the arguments need to be evaluated in the order they appear, but passed to the method in the original order. The following example shows this:

```java
// --- kotlin code ---
fun add(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
fun useAddPositional() { println(add(1, 2)) }
fun useAddNamed() { println(add(a = 1, b = 2)) }
fun useAddReordered() { println(add(b = 2, a = 1)) }


// --- decompiled bytecode (simplified) ---
int add(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}

void useAddPositional() {
  int var0 = add(1, 2);
  System.out.println(var0);
}

void useAddNamed() {
  int var0 = add(1, 2);
  System.out.println(var0);
}

void useAddReordered() {
  byte var0 = 1;
  byte var1 = 2;
  int var2 = add(var0, var1);
  System.out.println(var2);
}
```

So even with swapped arguments, there is not much of a performance hit, as the kotlin compiler orders the arguments at compile time. There is, however, a scenariocase in which there is at least some cost in performance (although not as high as that of a hashmap would be): If the called method has default parameters, a helper method is generated, which takes all arguments and an additional bitmask describing which parameters should get the default value (plus an unused dummy parameter whose purpuse I don't know). This helper method needs to check for every argument if it was passed or not:

```java
// --- kotlin code ---
fun add(a: Int = 1, b: Int = 2, c: Int = 3) = a + b
fun useAddPositional() { println(add(1, 2)) }
fun useAddNamed() { println(add(a = 1, b = 2)) }
fun useAddReordered() { println(add(b = 2, a = 1)) }
fun useAddAllParameters() { println(add(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)) }


// --- decompiled bytecode (simplified) ---
int add(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}

// generated method
int add$default(int var0, int var1, int var2, Object var3) {
  if ((var2 & 0b001) != 0) var0 = 1;
  if ((var2 & 0b010) != 0) var1 = 2;
  if ((var2 & 0b100) != 0) var1 = 3;
  return add(var0, var1);
}

void useAddPositional() {
  int var0 = add$default(1, 2, 0, 0b100, (Object)null);
  System.out.println(var0);
}

void useAddNamed() {
  int var0 = add$default(1, 2, 0, 0b100, (Object)null);
  System.out.println(var0);
}

void useAddReordered() {
  byte var0 = 0;
  byte var1 = 1;
  byte var2 = 2;
  int var3 = add$default(var1, var2, var0, 0b100, (Object)null);
  System.out.println(var3);
}

void useAddAllParameters() {
  // note: add() method is called directly!
  int var0 = add(1, 2, 3);
  System.out.println(var0);
}
```

So when having a function with default parameters and calling it with only a *subset* of those, additional if-checks are performed. But here too, it doesn't matter if you use named parameters or not, only if you change the argument order.